# regular expression - excluding results if string is present

Tags: regex

Trying to create a regular expression that excludes results of a substring is present.

Data Set:

```
 http://www.cnn.com/test1
 http://www.cnn.com/test3
 http://www.cnn.com/test5
 http://www.stackflow.com/test4
 http://www.cnn.com/test3
 http://www.cnn.com/test4
```

exclude:

- find all cnn.com sites
- that don't have /test3

Results:

```
 http://www.cnn.com/test1
 http://www.cnn.com/test5
 http://www.cnn.com/test4
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: `(www.cnn.com)(?!/test3)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid matching strings like `http://www.cnn.com/test/test3` then you can use a negtive lookbehind at the end of the string

```
cnn\.com.*(?<!test3)$
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this would be fastest:

```
cnn\.com(?!\/test3)[a-zA-Z0-9-._~:?#@!$&'*+,;=`.\/\(\)\[\]]*
```

because you restrict the URL to [allowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/1150683) only.